# Changing value of json object

Tags: swift

I receive an object from the server

```
var profileDictionary = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("profile") 
print("profileDictionary: \(profileDictionary)")
```

that looks like the console output at the bottom.

I want to change the [name][first] field (unfortunately Elon is not yet a customer), and send the object back to the server to update the record.  How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
profileDictionary["name"]!["first"] as String = "Karlos"
```

but it gives the error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'

I have also tried

```
profileDictionary!["name"]!!["first"]  = "Karlos"
```

then the error is:
Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'

If I change profileDictionary to NSDictionary

```
var profileDictionary = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("profile") as! NSDictionary
profileDictionary["name"]!["first"]  = "Karlos"
```

I get the same error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'

With SwiftyJSON I can easily change a value, but it mess up the type, turning 1 into true for example.

How can I change a value in this object?

Any help at all is very much appreciated!  Thank you.

Console output

```
Optional({
    address =     {
        city = "";
        country = nor;
        lineOne = "";
        lineTwo = "";
        zip = "";
    };
    card =     {
        last4 = 4242;
        verified = 1;
    };
    filledOut = 1;
    name =     {
        first = Elon;
        last = Musk;
    };
    phone = 911;
    validated = 1;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
    if let profileDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("profile") as? NSMutableDictionary {

        if let nameDict:NSMutableDictionary = profileDictionary["name"] as? NSMutableDictionary {
            nameDict["first"] = "Karlos";
        }

        print("profileDictionary: \(profileDictionary)")
    }
```

Comment: This works, is there a reason for the down vote? Inefficient ?

Comment: @karlml, I don't think, there is any issue in the code. if it is working fine, then go for it ignoring the down vote.

Comment: I have to select this answer as it was the one that actually solved the problem.  I would however, ideally have liked to do it in a 100% swift way.

Comment: @karlml, NSMutableDictionary class is still supported by swift so there is no harm in using it. As far as using Dictionary<String,String> or [String:String], you may use it but the validation would be the issue while unwrapping the object. Abhinav's solution has the same issue. he is unwrapping the dictionary without validation which may cause crashing because there could be a scenario (maybe in future) where you do not find the "name" key.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out (a **complete swift implementation**):

```
var profileDictionary = ["address" : ["city" : "" , "country" : "nor" , "lineOne" : "" , "lineTwo" : "", "zip" : ""], "card" : ["last4" : 4242 , "verified" : 1] , "filledOut" : 1 , "name" : ["first" : "Elon" , "last" : "Musk"] , "phone" : 911 , "validated" : 1]

print(profileDictionary) // This prints first name as Elon

var nameDict = profileDictionary["name"] as! Dictionary<String,String>
nameDict["first"] = "Karlos"
profileDictionary["name"] = nameDict

print(profileDictionary) // This prints first name as Karlos
```

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding your answer, but how can I make profileDictionary look like the one you have typed out ?

Comment: Just ignore first line. I did that in Xcode playground just to test with your console output.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work.  First it complains at var nameDict = profileDictionary["name"] as! Dictionary<String,String>   ERROR:  Value of optional type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?.  If i change to :  var nameDict = profileDictionary!["name"] as! Dictionary<String,String>.   I get the same error at  profileDictionary["name"] = nameDict .    If I fix it to         profileDictionary!["name"] = nameDict  the error change to :  Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'

Comment: These issues are coming because you are loading the dictionary from server and I created it locally. You end up sorting first issue well. For the last one - clearly, your `profileDictionary ` is not mutable meaning it is probably defined with `let` and not `var` which is why it is not allowing you to change the `name` key of `profileDictionary `.

Comment: I tried to change it to var, but it does not help, only casting it as! NSMutableDictionary works     
´let profileDictionary = users.allDocuments[0].valueForKey("profile") as! NSMutableDictionary´

Is this wrong?

Comment: No, it's not. Go ahead with it. It's just you are using objective c syntax.

Comment: Ok, so how can I use swift?  Or is it difficult to know without having the actual object from the server?

Comment: While parsing server JSON response, try by creating mutable containers like --> `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Always happy to help :). Did it work for you? If so, could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.